# Fedora 36 KDE update broke my installation

Tags: networking, fedora, plasma

Unfortunately the latest update to Fedora 36 KDE I applied (2/28/2023 ~21:00 EST) in my system BROKE my installation. I simply did a run of the mill `sudo dnf update`, not a version upgrade and now my system is broken.

When I log in using plasma X11 it keeps crashing (a dialog appears telling me of the crash and also that I can’t report it because plasma is crashed), Wi-Fi is down and plasma keeps reverting to default display configuration (making my laptop screen primary instead of secondary). Plasma Wayland doesn’t crash but still isn’t of much help since I'm still unable to connect to Wi-Fi (I’m writing this from my phone) because it says the agent isn’t running in order to retrieve my password… BUT inserting the password manually into the network manager doesn’t connect to my Wi-Fi either.

Plasma looks weird too, it’s like something changed about it. Has anyone experienced this? How can I get my system back to work again? How can I get the Wi-Fi back to work? That way I could maybe downgrade plasma and see how it goes since using the older kernel didn’t help. And could I revert the update using dnf history?

Sorry if this isn’t the best place to report this… Would appreciate suggestions. Browsing these sites using mobile isn’t the most intuitive.

Comment: Have you tried `dnf history rollback ...`?  You can rollback upgrades to try to get back to the state before your latest `dnf upgrade`, but I wonder if all configuration files will be returned to their previous state.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I did not do an upgrade but an update. It should not have broken my system.

Comment: `update` is a deprecated alias for [`upgrade`](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#upgrade-command).

Comment: Ah, good to know. In the end I connected to the internet via ethernet and downgraded a few plasma packages. Which didn't seem to fix anything.. Then I upgraded others and now desktop seems to be fully working although I'm getting a kernel core error right after I login to my account (Plasma x11)... Not sure why and I don't want to hit another upgrade for now. I'll wait and see. Looks like the upgrade process failed in some way. I'll definitely partclone back up before hitting another dnf upgrade.